# How to start next shell script only if previous returned 0?

Tags: linux, shell, deployment

I have a shell script that runs two other shell scripts from inside:

```
compile.sh
run.sh
```

First script can return error because compiler doesn't compile.

How do I run `run.sh` only if `compile.sh` returns 0?

Comment: `./compile.sh ;if [ $? -eq 0 ];then ./run.sh ;fi` for mutiple instructions

Answer (score 1):

use the `&&` operator which is basically like a logical and, it wouldn't go to the next command if the first one failed (returned a falsie value).

```
compile.sh && run.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

From [GNU Bash shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) documentation:

- `command1 && command2`  : command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero. (This is the one you want)
- `command1 || command2` : command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns a non-zero exit status.
- `command1 & command2` : command1 is executed asynchronously in a subshell (in the background)
- `command1 ; command2` : The shell waits for command1 to terminate, then proceeds with command2 whatever the exit status of command1.